# Validate bad formatted date in JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, validation, date, jackson

I am currently using the objectMapper of Jackson to serialise values in a JSON and put them in  a POJO. I need to validate those values so I use validation annotation such as @Regex, @Max and others.

So what happens for now is that I call objectMapper method to read JSON

```
publicEnquiry = objectMapper.readValue(jsonNode, Enquiry.class);
```

Then I retrieve all the validation messages in a list and I return it to the user.

```
payload = publicEnquiry.getPayload();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Enquiry<payload>>> constraintViolations =
            publicEnquiry.getConstraintViolations();
```

Everything works fine if I send a too big integer, a bad formatted string, or anything that will not create a problem for the serialisation, but if I send a date formatted in an unexpected format, or simply bad formatted like "2010-02" instead of "2010-02-03", then I get a JsonMappingException. It is of course expected because the mapper can't understand a bad-formatted date.

However, I need to manage those exception and to be able to add a validation message each time it happens, in a way that will seem transparent for the user. I need a message like "Validation failed: the expected format is yyyy-MM-dd". And I need to perform the normal validation on the other properties opf the POJO like in a normal case.

Unfortunately, Jackson doesn't offer a method in the objectMapper that would skip the exception-generator fields and give back a list of those troublesome fields, or anything like that. It simply fails if there is a problem.

Does someone would have a solution or at least a suggestion on how to proceed ?

Comment: Map the date as a String and convert it yourself.

Comment: Would love too, but I can't change the POJO to change the property from date to string

Comment: Then unmarshal the object yourself.  Tain't that hard.

Comment: In fact I have to try resolve bugs on a preexisting project, I can't make big changes sadly. And in this case the JSON to serialise contains something like 30 objects, not so easy to do

Comment: You can always deserialize the JSON, modify it, then reserialize to pass to your existing kluge.